# Missing link_faces on mesh

Tags: python, scripting, import, bmesh

I have a script that iterates through the polygons and link_faces of a mesh, and it has worked great. I am trying to make a conversion to .usd instead of .fbx in my mesh pipeline for a couple unrelated reasons, but I am having issues with getting bad results with meshes imported as .usd compared to identical .fbx meshes. (Some of the functions involve flattening areas of the mesh, and it leaves holes in the place instead).

I have tracked the issue down to some polys returning poly.link_faces as (0, 1 or 2) when the .fbx returns all 3's with the occasional 2. So I believe I have a disconnect somewhere, is there a way to repair those missing relationships? Or is .usd not going to be a viable solution?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using remove doubles and it solved the linked polygon issue with my mesh, and also didn't destroy my UV's.